# Account picker and google play store policy

Tags: android, google-play, account, picker

I created an app that is going to be in the app store soon, however, i used user's gmail account and prompted him via AccountPicker class for the first time when he installs an app (or when he deletes an active gmail account) what gmail account he wants to use and stored left side of his gmail as a username in a database (johndoe@gmail.com -> username: johndoe). Im just curious right now, what is google play store policy regarding email manipulation, has anyone had problems with this approach even though i ask user for the first time when user enters an app to choose his gmail account or leave the app?

Comment: what do you mean by "email manipulation"? if I understand correctly you're just using the user's email as your user id without any manipulation. I guess as long as you state on your app TOS that you're storing the user email everything should be fine

Comment: Well, storing one's email into a database can be considered as manipulation to someone, or i am mistaken? Anyways thank you for reply, i've never added any app into play store so i am a little bit cautious :)